# Using a 1D array of bytes in 2D way

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I am trying to use a 1D array of bytes in a 2D way, I want to be able to have 2 bytes per "row", and within these rows i have a small amount of code which is the following:

```
x /= 8;
```

this is because i have a function with a x and y parameter, the x parameter is the position of the bit inside the byte, and the y is the row number, and as i want two bytes per row, which would make each row 16 bits long and if i wanted to edit the second byte in the first row i would pass to the function, for example: 10 for the x value, and 0 for the y value which makes the second byte in the first row equal to 00100000.

i achieve this with an if statement:

```
if (xBefore >= 8) {
    xBefore -= 8;
}
```

that if i were to enter 10 for the x parameter 8 would be removed from 10 as that is one byte and the next byte would take the number from left to right with the following code:

```
tmp[y][x] |= (1 << 7 - xBefore);
```

i am able to achieve this functionality with a 2d array but how would i achieve this with a 1d array?

Comment: The way you describe the indexing is sort of "little endian". That is, if you think of each "row" as a 16 bit value, the most significant bit is bit 0. Is that required for interoperability with some existing code? Because, if not, the operations will be a little cleaner if you use a different internal representation.

Comment: could you please give a code-type example of how this would work?

Comment: seems like an XY problem (pun slightly intended)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need:

```
y *= 2;
if (x >= 8) {
    x -= 8;
    y += 1;
}
```

and you can then just use `tmp[y]` to access the appropriate byte and `x` to access the desired bit.

You could also investigate the [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class which allows you to treat a byte array as an array of 16 bit `short` values, in whichever "endian" format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-frame the problem and see if it helps. Suppose one needs an API like this:

```
interface BitMap {

  /**
   * Set or clear a flag at the given coordinates.
   */
  void set(int x, int y, boolean flag);

  /**
   * Test whether a given coordinate is true or false.
   */
  boolean get(int x, int y);

}
```

If you don't really care about the internal representation—for example, you don't have to expose it to an existing API that expects a sequence of bytes structured in a specific way—I recommend using [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) as a simple and robust representation:

```
final class BitMapImpl
  implements BitMap
{

  private final int w, h;

  private final BitSet bits;

  BitMapImpl(int w, int h)
  {
    if (w < 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("w < 0: " + w);
    if (h < 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("h < 0: " + h);
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    bits = new BitSet(w * h);
  }

  @Override
  public void set(int x, int y, boolean flag)
  {
    check(x, y);
    int i = y * w + x;
    bits.set(i, flag);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean get(int x, int y)
  {
    check(x, y);
    int i = y * w + x;
    return bits.get(i);
  }

  private void check(int x, int y)
  {
    if (x < 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("x < 0: " + x);
    if (x >= w)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("x >= w: " + x);
    if (y < 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("y < 0: " + y);
    if (y >= h)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("y >= h: " + y);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    hf(str);
    for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
      str.append('|');
      for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
        str.append(get(x, y) ? '*' : ' ');
      str.append('|');
      str.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    hf(str);
    return str.toString();
  }

  private void hf(StringBuilder str)
  {
    str.append('+');
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
      str.append('-');
    str.append('+');
    str.append(System.lineSeparator());
  }

  /* Demonstrate usage */
  public static void main(String... argv)
  {
    BitMap map = new BitMapImpl(2, 12);
    for (int y : new int[]{1, 2, 4, 8})
      for (int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
        map.set(x, y, true);
    map.set(1, 6, true);
    map.set(1, 10, true);
    System.out.println(map);
  }

}
```

Comment: I suspect the OP is reading / writing the binary data to a file (hence 1D byte array)

Comment: `BitSet` exposes conversions to and from a byte array to make it easy to read and write.